# "burn as file or burn content" Which should I choose?

Tags: iso, burning

I've downloaded ubuntu 12.04 image file and then I want to burn to a CD but when I tried to write the disc i getting notication "burn as file or burn content".

[image]

Which should I choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want to do

- If you want to unarchive the iso to files then select `Burn Contents` (creating a bootable ISO)
- If you want to burn the iso file as a file then select `Burn as file`. This will copy the ISO file as whole to the CD.

Comment: "Burn Content" it means to make a bootable disk for ubuntu image file. right?

Comment: @MuhammadSholihin yes.

Comment: @nixgadgets An ISO image is not compressed.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yup good point. my selection of word isnt obviously right so I changed it to unarchive.

Comment: @nixgadgets You're probably looking for the word "extract." I recommend that over "unarchive," since "unarchive" implies that an ISO image is an archive. An ISO image shares some characteristics with an archive and can be treated as an archive, but it is not really an archive, it is a disk image.

Comment: @EliahKagan If it is a disk image, then the correct option to create a bootable disk shouldn't be "Burn as file"?