# Can Startup Disk Creator make a bootable CD/DVD?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-cd, dvd, burning

I cannot create a bootable DVD disc using "Startup Disk Creator."

It is creating bootable USB drives smoothly, but it shows "no space" when trying to create a bootable DVD disc.

We need to create a bootable DVD disc because some old machines do not have the option of booting from USB devices.

System Information:

- Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS (32 bit)
- Starter Disk Creator: Available
- K3B: Available

Comment: Startup Disc Creator does not create bootable DVD's but USB's. For DVD's you need a Disk burner like brasero, k3b, etc. K3B is my favourite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For burning the DVD, Startup Disk Creator is the wrong tool for the job. Startup Disk Creator will not burn DVDs--its purpose is just [to write bootable ISO images to USB flash drives and SD cards](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/).

---

You said you have [K3b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3b). That will burn DVDs, so you may wish to use that. Burning an Ubuntu ISO image with K3b is covered in the [Burning from Kubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Burning_from_Kubuntu) section of ["BurningIsoHowto" in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

> 1. Insert a blank CD ***[or DVD]*** into your burner. Open K3b from the KickOff menu.
> 2. On the near bottom of the application where it says "Welcome to K3b - The CD and DVD Kreator" click "more actions..." and then pick "Burn Image".
>
>    [image: kubuntu_1.png]
> 3. Start the burning process.
> 4. You can use the default settings.
> 5. After burning completed, verify that your CD contains multiple files and folders and not just the ISO file. This way you will know
>      the process was performed correctly.

<sup>— [BurningIsoHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) by ["Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License), reproduced here (with slight modification) **as permitted by [the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)** under which both Ubuntu help wiki and user-contributed Ask Ubuntu content are provided. This is only part of that wiki page. **I have altered its formatting and spelling slightly and removed a broken link.**</sup>

---

For more information on burning an Ubuntu ISO image to a DVD in Ubuntu, see:

- [**How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)
- ["CdDvd/Burning" in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning)
- ["burn as file or burn content" Which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280551/burn-as-file-or-burn-content-which-should-i-choose)
- [How to burn an ISO-image into a DVD on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307742/how-to-burn-an-iso-image-into-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

Comment: But just burning of the "iso" image will make the DVD disc bootable?

Comment: @NaturalDivine Provided you burn it properly, yes. The Ubuntu ISO image contains the necessary data to be bootable both when written to a USB flash drive and when burned to a CD/DVD. Note that when you look at the contents of the burned DVD, you should see various files and folders. You should not see a single .iso file burned to the DVD. In K3b the "burn image" action should do what you want.